# Image Website => Picasa or Flickr?

Tags: image, flickr, picasa

I have just a simple question ! Basically, I want to make a website with lots of images (users contributions). I already have the host, but it's limited in disk space (10 Gigas). I know it represents a huge amount of image, but I prefer planning this, and host them elsewhere before the disk is full. I was thinking of Flickr and Google Picasa, but I can't decide which to use.
Can anyone help me ?

If you need more informations about my project, comment this post, and I'll edit it to answer you.

Thanks.
Regards rom France ;)

EDIT : Thanks to @premiso, I'm going towards Flickr I think. Anyone can give me a feedback on Premium Accounts ? Nevermind, I'm putting to solved :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have their limitations:

[Flickr's Limitations](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/)

[Picasa Album Limits](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98898)

[Picasa / Google Storage](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=10765)

I am not sure how this ranks today but here is a post about the two side by side: [Picasa VS Flickr](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/12/picasa-web-albums-vs-flickr-which.html)

Hopefully there is some good material there for your to choose which one. Good luck buddy!

Comment: Thanks for the infos ! It seems that Flickr is by far the more interesting ! 25$ a year for unlimited disk space, number of photos and bandwidth is kinda cheap I think... Especially when you look at Picasa Web Albums cost per Giga...

Comment: Not a problem, if this answered question, please mark the answer as such. Thanks.